# Can x.y and x['y'] ever result in different behavior for Host Objects?

Tags: javascript, properties, host-object

For a normal ("Native") JavaScript objects, where the property name is a valid identifier, the expressions `x.y` and `x["y"]` are always semantically equivalent.

*Is this equivalency guaranteed for [Host Objects](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.8)?*

> [..an] object supplied by the host environment to complete the execution environment of ECMAScript.

If not, are there notable exceptions? (In Cocoon, Crosswalk, IE, etc?)

In particular I am interested in the Window (`window`) and other DOM Objects; and if there are any known "exceptions" to the expected behavior, or if there are any environments in where such is possible.

Comment: Using bracket notation is the same as dot notation, everywhere, as it's in the ECMA specs.

Comment: Well `x.1` has different behavior than `x["1"]`, but that about syntax, not semantics. It would be no different for native / host objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be identical.  From Section 11.2.1 (Property Accessors) of the [Ecma-262 Edition 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/), we have:

> Properties are accessed by name, using either the dot notation:
>
> ```
> MemberExpression . IdentifierName 
> CallExpression . IdentifierName
> ```
>
> or the bracket notation:
>
> ```
> MemberExpression [ Expression ]
> CallExpression [ Expression ]
> ```
>
> The dot notation is explained by the following syntactic conversion:
>
> ```
> MemberExpression . IdentifierName
> ```
>
> is identical in its behaviour to
>
> ```
> MemberExpression [ <identifier-name-string> ]
> ```
>
> and similarly
>
> ```
> CallExpression . IdentifierName
> ```
>
> is identical in its behaviour to
>
> ```
> CallExpression [ <identifier-name-string> ]
> ```